# Typeahead with bloodhound remote suggestions

Tags: jquery, local, remote-server, typeahead.js, bloodhound

Here is my code:

```
tagsProcessor(){
        const suggestions = [{value: 'string1'}, {value: 'string2'}, {value: 'string3'}, {value: 'string4'}, {value: 'string5'}]
        var bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          sufficient: 3,
          local: suggestions,
          remote: {
            url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/suggestions',
          }
        });

        const $tagsInput = $('#tagsInput')
        $tagsInput.typeahead({
          hint: true,
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'suggestions',
          displayKey: 'value',
          source: bloodhoundSuggestions
        });

    }
}
```

It's works with local suggestions fine, but it doesn't works with remote for some reason.

The url `http://localhost:3001/api/suggestions` returns an array of objects, the similar one to the `suggestions` constant.

Why no suggestions from remote shows up in the typeahead input?

I'm getting this error in console right after this function receives remote suggestions:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   jQuery.extend.each @ libs.js:358
>   _.each @ libs.js:17928 processRemote @ libs.js:18763 onResponse @ libs.js:18515 done @ libs.js:18254 jQuery.Callbacks.fire @
>   libs.js:3148 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ libs.js:3260 done @
>   libs.js:9314 jQuery.ajaxTransport.options.send.callback @ libs.js:9718

**Update 1**
My remote data is returned by nodeJS server API:

```
router.route('/suggestions')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.json([{value: 'data10'}, {value: 'data30'}, {value: 'data20'}, {value: 'data40'}, {value: 'data50'}])
  });
```

**Update 2**
I'm sure I receive the correct answer from server, because i see it in console.log:

```
var bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: suggestions,
  remote: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/suggestions',
    transform: function(argument) {
            console.log('argument', argument)
            return argument
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: Your remote file is an Array? or Json?

Comment: i've added an answer in the description

Comment: How many input have you on your Json? Because remote is limited

Comment: 5 currently, i've posted the real response in description

Comment: Can you use the Network panel or a packet sniffer to make sure that your remote server is responding the exact same way as your local server? It looks like it isn't parsing the response correctly.

Comment: Thank you Nate, I've added the answer in the description

Comment: The plugin expects sources will return an array of objects, not an array of strings. You'll want to use the remote filter option. Source: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote

Comment: i don't get it, what remote filter option?
Also, the api returns exactly the array of objects

Comment: Are you using Express with Node.js for getting the remote data? Looks like you are but thought I'd double check. If so what version are you using?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: OP, did the helpful answer below help at all? Please respond to it in some fashion (e.g. accept it).

Answer (score 5):

An example of your code working with a remote data source is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ka0v6bg7/

Try searching for strings beginning with "data" or "string" (note, querying for "data" will take a little longer as it's a remote datasource!)

The only thing I've changed is the remote datasource.

Hence things to check are:

1) That you are correctly referencing typeahead. Try referencing it from here:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js
```

as a test.

2) The Jquery error suggests that it may not be referenced correctly. Again, as a test try referencing JQuery from here:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Did my answer help as I showed you how to get your code working with a remote data source?