# twitter.typeahead.js doesn't work in asp.net core mvc project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, twitter-typeahead

I am working on a asp.net mvc project which will show the related search results ahead typing below the search box. I've added the twitter.typeahead.js with bower package manager in the project. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="~/lib/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bloodhound">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
            'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
            'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
            'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
            'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
            'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
            'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
            'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        var states = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
            local: states
        });

        $('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
            {
                name: 'states',
                source: states
            });
    });
</script>
```

Now it's giving this error

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.Use defaultPrevented instead.
>   TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function. jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).typeahead is not a function @http://localhost:54331/Home/Search:85:9
>   j@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js:2:29997
>   g/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js:2:30313
>    undefined

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "typeahead.js",
  "version": "0.11.1",
  "main": "dist/typeahead.bundle.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.7",
    "jasmine-ajax": "~1.3.1",
    "jasmine-jquery": "~1.5.2"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js",
  "_release": "0.11.1",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v0.11.1",
    "commit": "87de059a7820b1e223f1c704fa12a624dbce3a4f"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js.git",
  "_target": "v0.11.1",
  "_originalSource": "typeahead.js",
  "_direct": true
}
```

Comment: try jQuery version 1.10 for testing if error appears ?

Comment: It says "jQuery is not defined" and also "$ is not defined" after trying this!

Comment: @MohitK.Bhowmik what **src** you have tried for jquery 1.1?

Comment: are you sure that typeahead.bundle.js doesn't return 404 error ? check if it's loaded correctly

Comment: 1) Share Screenshot. 2) Check if only one jQuery plugin is included in page 3) Add jQuery above typeScript plugin 4) Check if typescript called in document ready

Comment: @MJK <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"
     integrity="sha256-iqD4S1Mx78w8tyx9UEwrxuvYYdoAPXLDPfmc5lDUUx0="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: @MohitK.Bhowmik try this `<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @jolly.exe Mohit K doestn't have enough reputation to share the screenshot

Comment: @bRIMOs doesn't return 404 error!

Comment: @jolly.exe there's only one jQuery plugin is included; i added jQuery above typescript plugin; yes, typescript is called in document ready!

Comment: @MohitK.Bhowmik please tell me version of typeahead u are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get this working :P

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/6ydvth9q/1/

**TypeAhead** version 1.1.1
URL: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.1.1/typeahead.jquery.min.js

**jQuery** is latest

**Source**: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

TypeScript code is without **Bloodhound** I dont know why this is for :D

**HTML**

```
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push(str);
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
        'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
        'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
        'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
        'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to clarify, Bloodhound is not the issue.

[Bloodhoud](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) is the typeahead.js suggestion engine

There is a jsfiddle added on this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082444/typeahead-with-bloodhound-remote-suggestions), that works perfectly with bloodhound.

I have also created one [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jobair/sm9s6gnn/) with the updated version typhead bloodhound and jquery version

> Jquery: 3.2.1
>   Typehead: 1.1.1

You could try this version for your project

```
const suggestions = [{
    value: 'bloodhound1'
}, {
    value: 'bloodhound2'
}, {
    value: 'bloodhound3'
}, {
    value: 'typeahead1'
}, {
    value: 'typeahead2'
}]

var bloodhoundSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    sufficient: 3,
    local: suggestions
});

const $tagsInput = $('#tagsInput')
$tagsInput.typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    name: 'suggestions',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: bloodhoundSuggestions
});
```